# Many LUNs per Partition or one LUN with many partitions

Tags: rhel, partition, raid

RedHat 6.x, 3par

23 raw "disks" for informix are required

Is it better to have 23 LUNs, each chunk will have its own LUN
or is it better to have just one big LUN containing 23 raw partitions.
Better meaning: Overall performance, is there a serious overhead for linux when you have to handle such many luns ... etc.

I would go for 23 LUNs rather than this partition party.
Or doesn't matter at all ?